# If $f'(-1)>0$ and $f'(1)<0$ there exists a zeropoint $x$ for $f'$ and also $f''(x)<0$

Tags: real-analysis

This was an excercise in my exam and I am not sure whether my solution is Right or not.

First I have said because of intermediatevaluetheorem a zeropint must exist. Then I have said that one can assume without loss of generality that $f'(y)<0$ for $x>y$ and $f'(y)>0$ for $y>x$ where $y\in[-1,1]$. I dont know why we can assume that without loss of generality. I.e. why we can assume there exists a $x$ for which is $f'(x)=0$ and there is a neighbourhood of x such that if $y$ is in the neighbourhood and smaller/bigger than x the value is biger/smalller than $0$?

Comment: The problem statement is very incomplete. What is the domain of $f$? How smooth is $f$? ...

Answer (score 4):

This is false. Let $f(x)=-x^{4}$. Then $f'(1)=-4<0,f'(-1)=4>0$ and $f'(x)=0$ only when $x=0$. At this point $f''(x)=0$.

If you replace $f''(x)<0$ by $f''(x) \leq 0$ then the result is true. Let $\xi =\sup \{x:f'(x)>0\}$. A simple verification shows that $f'(\xi)=0$ and $f''(\xi) \leq 0$.

Answer (score 3):

With no other assumptions about $f$, the statement is false. For example, take the function $f(x)=-|x|$.

Then $f'(-1) = 1 > 0$ and $f'(1) = -1 < 0$ are both true, but there is no zero point of $f'$.